# Tab bar image not working

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uiapplication, openurl

I need your help here.
My app has 5 tab bars.
The first tab bar's image will be missing after make a phone call using openURL.
And this is only happen when running the app in iOS 8/9.

Below is the coding  where I make a phone call:

```
-(void)callDistributor
{
   NSString *phoneNo= [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:phoneNumber_];
   phoneNo = [phoneNo stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNo]];
}
```

Below is the coding (in delegate.m) where the tab bars are created:

```
- (void)addCustomTabbar {
  NSArray *array =
  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"products",
   @"fav",
   @"buy",
   @"about",
   @"settings", nil];

  UIImage *buttonImage, *buttonImageSelected;

  for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
    NSString *active =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_active.png", [array objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSString *inActive =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", [array objectAtIndex:i]];

    buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:inActive];
    buttonImageSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:active];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.tag = i;
    button.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                               UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                               UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |
                               UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin);

    CGFloat heightDifference =
    buttonImage.size.height -
    tabBarController_.tabBar.frame.size.height;
    button.frame = CGRectMake(i * buttonImage.size.width,
                              tabBarController_.view.frame.size.height -
                              tabBarController_.tabBar.frame.size.height - 1 - heightDifference,
                              buttonImage.size.width,
                              buttonImage.size.height);

    [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImageSelected
                      forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(changeTabbar:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button setSelected:(i == 0)];

    [tabBarController_.view addSubview:button];
  }

    addedTabBar_ = YES;
}

- (void)changeTabbar:(id)sender {
  int tagNum = [sender tag];

  tabBarController_.selectedIndex = tagNum;

  for (UIView *view in tabBarController_.view.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
      UIButton *button = (UIButton *)view;
      [button setSelected:(tagNum == button.tag)];
    }
  }
}
```

Only the first tab bar will missing after phone call, the other 4 tab bars are working fine.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.